# finding sum of values found from a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns two rows of data as count. I want to find sum of the column values. My sql:

```
(SELECT count(memberid) count 
   FROM `friendRequest`, Member 
   where status = 2 and memberid = sender and receiver = 19) 
UNION 
(SELECT count(memberid) count 
   FROM `friendRequest`, Member 
   where status = 2 and memberid = receiver and sender = 19)
```

I have tried using `Select Sum(my above query)` but I am getting error. I just need some of above values.

Comment: SUM should do it....what error are you getting?

Comment: what's the error you're getting when you're using SUM ?

Comment: yea, tell us what you want to do because I think that query can be improve

Comment: I just tried your SQL, and had no problem....

Comment: Did you alias your `SELECT Sum(my above query)` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can grab both result sets in a single query:

```
SELECT count(memberid) count 
FROM `friendRequest`, Member 
WHERE status = 2 AND (
    (memberid = sender AND receiver = 19) OR 
    (memderid = receiver AND sender = 19)
)
```

Comment: thanks Bort now it looks so simple. I had complicated the query

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(count)
FROM
  ...the rest of your query...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use aggregation, you need to group it by something using `GROUP BY`

```
(SELECT count(memberid) SUM(count) 
   FROM `friendRequest`, Member 
   where status = 2 and memberid = sender and receiver = 19
   GROUP BY Member) 
UNION 
(SELECT count(memberid) SUM(count) 
   FROM `friendRequest`, Member 
   where status = 2 and memberid = receiver and sender = 19
   GROUP BY Member)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work as is

```
SELECT SUM(count)
FROM   (
         (SELECT count(memberid) count 
          FROM `friendRequest`, Member 
          where status = 2 and memberid = sender and receiver = 19) 
          UNION 
         (SELECT count(memberid) count 
          FROM `friendRequest`, Member 
          where status = 2 and memberid = receiver and sender = 19)
       ) AS anyAliasWillDo
```

but I would strongly advise you to stop using implicit joins *(obsolete)* and start using explicit join syntax. The statement then becomes

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT)
FROM   (
            SELECT  COUNT(memberid) AS COUNT 
            FROM    `friendRequest` AS fr
                    INNER JOIN Member AS m ON m.memberid = fr.sender
            WHERE   status = 2 AND receiver = 19 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  COUNT(memberid) AS COUNT 
            FROM   `friendRequest` AS fr 
                    INNER JOIN Member AS m ON m.memberid = fr.receiver
            WHERE   status = 2 AND sender = 19
        ) AS AnyAliasWillDo
```

Comment: Doesn't an aggregation function(SUM) need a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik - Not as written here. As written in your answer, yes, it does.